# How to convert between LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I am having compatibility issues between a method in my repository and the calling method in my service layer.

The method in my repository class looks like this:

```
public TEntity Single(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
     // Code left out
}
```

And then the method in my service layer calling the above method would look like this:

```
public TDTOEntity Single(Expression<Func<TDTOEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
     return repository.Single(predicate).ProjectedAs<TDTOEntity>();
}
```

The error that I am getting is:

> Cannot convert from
>   `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TDTOEntity,bool>>` to
>   `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TEntity,bool>>`

How do I convert between the 2 expressions? Is something like this at all possible?

Comment: It's pretty clear that you have different input parameter for `Func` delegate

Comment: Thats pretty much impossible since you can't tell the compiler how TEntity and TDOTOEntity correlate. I think it would be possible to reconstruct the expression with reflection. Wouldn't want to burn my fingers on that one, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,  no solution if your service layer's method doesn't know about the repository entity.

This makes sense for all "mapping" systems : if you don't know the source AND the target, you're ... in trouble !

Cause even if there was no error coming from the arguments, how would `repository.Single` know which repository Entity is concerned ?

So you'll have to change your method either this way

```
public TDTOEntity Single<TEntity, TDTOEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
     return repository.Single(predicate).ProjectedAs<TDTOEntity>();
}
```

or this one (which wouldn't make sense if  `ProjectedAs` does enumeration, I hope that's not true. Assuming also that you have a method `All<TEntity>`, or something equivalent returning an `IQueryable<TEntity>`)

```
public TDTOEntity Single<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TDTOEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
     return repository.All<TEntity>().ProjectedAs<TDTOEntity>().Single(predicate);
}
```

These solutions could be slighly different with use of types as parameters and reflection, but... you need to know the relation between TEntity and TDTOEntity anyway.